# Variance of regression coefficients with indicator variables

Tags: regression, categorical-encoding

I'm not an expert in Mathese, so hopefully this makes some sense....

I have a least squares problem with a lot of predictors, many of which are indicator variables (0 or 1). I use a sparse matrix because of the number of predictors and rows. I solve with Gauss-Seidel regression and that works fine.

I'd like to calculate the variance of the coefficients. The standard method seems to be to invert the t(X)X matrix (where t(X) is the transpose of X) and the variance of each coefficient is the diagonal of this inverted matrix multiplied by the variance of the residuals.

Does it make sense to do this for coefficients with indicator variables? If so, how would I do this? The matrix is too large to invert, and iterative methods take ages and don't seem to give meaningful results.

Comment: It is meaningfull, but if your matrix is to large to be inverted then you have some other problem, and should tell us more about your context ...